# Push rejected, failed to compile Python app error Discord.py

Tags: git, heroku, discord.py

When I try to push my I get this error:

```
C:\Users\emirs\PycharmProjects\discordmasterbot>git push heroku master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.10
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite (from -r 
/tmp/build_9aeec3d177cff34ed7cd7b5bc8e84eca/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (to revision rewrite) to /tmp/pip-req-build-pexa63lg 
build-pexa63lg
remote:          Running command git clone -q https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py /tmp/pip-req- 
build-pexa63lg
remote:          WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'rewrite', assuming revision or ref.
remote:          Running command git checkout -q rewrite
remote:          error: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git.
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q rewrite Check the logs 
for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to discordmasterbot.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/discordmasterbot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/discordmasterbot.git'
```

And my requirements.txt is like that:

```
discord.py==1.3.3
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pandas
dnspython==1.16.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

And my programs "import" section:

```
import json
import os
import random
import shutil
from os import system
from random import randint
import praw
import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.utils import get
import aiohttp
from itertools import cycle
```

I really want to host my bot in Heroku, but I can't! I think that It might be a problem with the `requirements.txt` and so thats why I've put my whole import section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite` no longer exists, as rewrite is now the master branch and the async version (0.16.x) has been deprecated.

You can just replace that line in `requirements.txt` with `discord.py==1.3.3` (most recent version at the time of this answer) or remove `@rewrite` from the end.

Comment: i think it will work but git still didn't see the changes i made on requirements.txt

Comment: How do you mean? Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Could you edit your question with the updated `requirements.txt`?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the same error if your `requirements.txt` looks like that. Are you 100% sure you saved the file and that you're editing the correct one?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I think it didn't see the new changes i made. So I created a new file, copied the same text, named it as "requirements.txt" and saved it. Now It's working. Thank you for your help

Comment: Brilliant, that's great news! Glad to hear you fixed it, happy coding :^)